# globalVariables() function generates Missing name

Tags: global-variables, cran, r-package

I've got a package at https://github.com/histmr/Rekishi that generates the "no visible binding for global variable" on CMD check because I use a .Rda file to include data. I've tried adding

```
if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1") utils::globalVariables(c("kanji_conversion_table"))
```

to the Normalize.R file but that generates a different error

```
> document()
Updating Rekishi documentation
Loading Rekishi
Writing NAMESPACE
Warning: Normalize.R:13: Missing name
Deleting normalize_kanji.Rd
```

What am I doing wrong? Where do I add the globalVariables command?